# playing an animation in landscape mode in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

i am trying to play an animation in landscape mode in unity but as soon as the game start the phone turn in landscape mode and it quit without playing anything 
i have only one scene with a UI Image contain an animator and a simple animation 
this is the script of the image

```
AudioSource audio;

void Start () {
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    audio.Play ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(!audio.isPlaying)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("GameIntro");
    }
}
```

in `player setting` the default orientation is set to portrait 
if i comment this line `Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;` 
my game work fine and the animation play in the default orientation mode but if this code is set it quite right after the game start 
what would it be the problem ? am I missing something ?

Comment: Unity tag has nothing to do with Unity3d game engine on stack overflow. Please don't use it with this kind of question.

Comment: ok . sorry .. do you have an answer for my question ??

Comment: I suppose your problem is coming from somewhere else, I just reproduce your setup and it seems to work normally. Did you tried to set the default orientation to `LandscapeLeft`? Maybe you should try to initialize the rotation in an empty object instead of your image (only for the orientation).

Comment: i tried that it didn't work , the UI image is set to be full screen ,and the canvas is set to fit screen size , and the image contain the animator and this script only . that's it . when i try the application on android it do this. it quit right away but u can see that the device orient to landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Animation Clips in Unity3D is not exactly Oriented Correctly even in Unity3d 5.

You would have to manually Fix it's offset to the correct XYZ set.

Meaning if you have Animated your GameObject <-  on Landscape and the Your Orientation Changes. It will still Animate based on its own GameObject XYZ not on WorldScene XYZ.

I hope this make sense to you. So to fix this problem. You can do 2 things.

1. Manually Lock your Orientation and reset your Animation. easiest Not Recommended but not Ideal.
2. Make your animation Correspond to WorldScene XYZ instead.

Comment: that's the answer that i was looking for . thank you :) , and that what i did in this past week i oriented my gameobject to be in a landscape view and it worked for me